# DOM xpath isn't working correctly

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I don't quite understand whats wrong with my xpath code. It's not returning any results. First, here's the code:

```
    $url = 'http://someurl.com';
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->loadHTML($url);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $query = '//div[@id="main"]//ul[@id="tags"]//li//a';
    $result = $xpath->query($query);
    foreach($result as $node){    
        $val = $node->getAttribute('href');
        echo $val."<br/>";
    }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div id="main">
    <ul id="tags">
    <li class="tag_col_0"><a href="/somevalue">somevalue</a></li>
    <li class="tag_col_0"><a href="/somevalue1">somevalue1</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

I'm not quite sure what's wrong here.

Comment: I dont see where you ever loaded the URL or HTML string...

Comment: @prodigitalson Sorry fixed that.

Comment: I'm also unsure what's wrong, because you did not tell us. What _is_ wrong, and in what way is it not "working correctly"?

Comment: I think it should get normalized, but you are also not closing your `a` tags...

Comment: @prodigitalson Updated HTML.

Comment: With an url, you must use `$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That's the answer. You should make it an acceptable answer.

Comment: But in addition, please replace the XPath expression with `//div[@id="main"]/ul[@id="tags"]/li/a`. You should not use `//` whenever the structure of a document is statically known.